# Using systemd-tmpfiles as ordinary user

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm trying to have a user-configured temporary files folder on a Debian system. I created the file ~/.config/user-tmpfiles.d/user.conf file with the content:

```
d /home/user/mytmpfiles 0750 user user 30d
```

However, /home/user/mytmpfiles is only created when I call:

```
$ systemd-tmpfiles --user --create
```

If I create that folder, old files inside it are not removed unless I explicitly call systemd-tmpfiles with the --clean option. It seems nothing reads the users configurations files for taking action, which seems strange. If I need to change some system file to call systemd-tmpfiles to check users' configuration files, then what is the point of having a user configuration file? Can I make mytmpfiles using systemd-tmpfiles without changing system configuration?

Comment: Is `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` enabled?

Comment: I was about to suggest creating a service which runs `systemd-tmpfiles` for you on login, and `--clean` on logout.  Then @ctx tells us there already is one!  `man systemd-tmpfiles` for details.

Comment: `sudo systemctl --global enable systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service`

Comment: I guess systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service is enabled, "systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service" tells me it is active. I don't know how to tell the system units from the user units, however. @ctx

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, you need to make sure the `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` is enabled:

```bash
sudo systemctl --global enable systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service # as root or
systemctl --user enable --now systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
# You might also want systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
```

You can "tell the system units from the user units" by passing `--user` to `systemctl`.